# JXLS inaccessible or unknown property

Tags: jxls

I'm trying to test the JXLS java library to generate an Excel file.

I keep on getting these error messages:

**1018 [AWT-EventQueue-0] WARN org.apache.commons.jexl2.JexlEngine  - org.jxls.expression.JexlExpressionEvaluator.evaluate@61![0,19]: 'transaction.account;' inaccessible or unknown property transaction**

I have followed all the steps from their web site.

This is my code:

```
*List<Transaction> transactions = generateTransactionData();
org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator.configure();

InputStream is = new java.io.FileInputStream(new File("rapport.xlsx"));
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("rapport-output.xlsx");

Context context = new Context();
context.putVar("transactions", transactions);

JxlsHelper.getInstance().processTemplate(is, os, context);*
```

---

```
class Transaction{

    private String account;


    Transaction(String _account){
        account = _account;
    }

    public String getAccount(){
        return account;
    }

}
```

My method generateTransactionData() returns an ArrayList of Transaction and there is no null values.

Anybody can help?

Comment: You may want to make your Transaction class public